# create dynamic drop-downs using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, dom, createelement

Hello i want to create dynamic drop-downs using javascript, but its not working..

My PHP code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:addRow();" value="Add Row" name="addRow"/>
```

My JS code:

```
// This function is used to create dynamic form element
function addRow() {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    element = document.createElement("select");
    element.setAttribute('id', 'focus');
    element.options.add(opt);
}
```

PS: It is not giving any js console error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont add the element to the body so it doesn't show up

```
// This function is used to create dynamic form element
function addRow() {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    element = document.createElement("select");
    element.setAttribute('id', 'focus');
    element.options.add(opt);
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: It should probably be added to the form, but hey.. :)

Comment: @SuneTrudslev Ssshhh, our secret :P